# loading SpriteSheets and using gameFrame work

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite-sheet

I reasonly started using SpriteSheets and blitting technic, yet it seems quite complicated stuff (for me). So I wonder is there a neat gameFrame Engine (or a way)that you do something like the Starling technic ( the starling MovieClip and juggler )but without the creation of the Starling environment.(cause as far as I know, I need to have a Starling stage where I can put stuff/do stuff with the starling code, and I cant just manipulate starling code directly inside the documentClass)

Something, something like:

```
var myMonkey_mcContainer : MovieClip = new MovieClip ( source to the spriteSheet, name of the elements to take, how many elements to take )
```

and this is done directly in the document Class, so if i want to move the myMonkey_mcContainer I`ll just do something like myMonkey_mcContainer.x = 50 or 100 or 200.

where before that I have a SpriteSheet with 10 pictures of the monkey in different position, and those pictures will have the name of "Monkey_1","Monkey_2","Monkey_3" etc.

I did try doing this directly Into the document class with Starling

```
monkeyArt:MovieClip = new MovieClip(Assets.getAtlas().getTextures("Monkey_"), 10);
        monkeyArt.x = 50
        monkeyArt.y = 50
        starling.core.Starling.juggler.add(monkeyArt);
        this.addChild(monkeyArt);
```

but it gives me something like

**1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.display:MovieClip to an unrelated type starling.something.something.**

I also tried creating my "own" blitting class (from the tuts out there) but it is complicated, and is it necessary?

I was looking in Flixel and PushButton but didnt quite get if what i wanted is possible with them.

So any suggestions or advice?

Comment: In short, you should write your own blitting engine. While yes, it's pretty complicated, it'll give you much needed experience in manipulating objects.

Comment: is it  that with that you are also telling me that there is no easy solution ( to be more exact ->the solution that Im searching for ) ?

Comment: I don't know if there is any "easy" solution, maybe there is, but you will first have to do a lot of work to make your sprite sheets comply with the engine. But surely nothing like a short sequence of AS3 commands will make you a MC out of several bitmaps.

Comment: well 10x for the info and for the heads up